# Using "self" as argument in scala constructor

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to understand the following class declaration from the source code of Apache Spark:

```
class PairRDDFunctions[K, V](self: RDD[(K, V)])
(implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null)
   extends Logging
   with SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil
   with Serializable
   {
```

What is the meaning of self here? Does it set self in the rest of the class to be equal to the RDD that is passed in?

Comment: Just a normal argument. No special meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is just the name of the argument being passed into the constructor. So a reference to your RDD will be held via a field named `self` (if it's used elsewhere in the class, the Scala compiler will create the corresponding field). It's analogous to (a simpler example)

```
class Point(x : Int, y : Int)
```

Perhaps there's simply some confusion here with the argument being named `self` and [explicitly typed self references](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html), which are often called `self`

```
  class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
    self: Node =>
```